# Coin Flipping Game -- St. Petersburg Variant?

Tags: probability, expected-value, infinite-games

Suppose Alice and Bob are playing a game with a fair coin. Every time the coin comes up heads, the score (initially 0) increases by 1. If the coin comes up tails, the score decreases by 1. If the score reaches -2 or 2, the game is over. Alice wins if the score is -2, and Bob wins if the score is 2.

The stake starts out as one dollar, but every turn, before the coin is flipped, Bob has the option of doubling the stake. What's his optimal strategy, and what's the EV of this strategy?

The payout is done by the loser, so this is a zero sum game.

One simple (but likely suboptimal) strategy for Bob is to double the stake every time the score is +1. I've done the calculation, and his expected value is $1.

To win as much as he can, I believe Bob should always double his stake when he has positive EV. Thus an optimal strategy appears to doubling his stake when the score is 0 and when the score is 1. But doing the calculation (using recursive states) seems to give a negative expected value--a bizarre contradiction I can't wrap my head around. Perhaps I've done the math wrong, but I can't help but think this is similar to the St. Petersburg paradox, where once in a while, Bob can win an insurmountably large amount of money. The only difference is that he might also lose it all--he's never guaranteed a positive payout.

I appreciate any thoughts on the problem.

Comment: We have a random walk with a fair coin, so the probability to win is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$ for Bob. So, the situation is the same as if he would just bet his money for "heads" and wins the amount if heads appears and loses otherwise.

Comment: Therefore, Bob can by only risking $1$ dollar in total, win an arbitary amount of money with a positive chance, of course this chance decreases with about the square root of the amount he wants to win. Doubling the stake is much more risky since in practice he cannot bet an arbitary amount. If he could, he could guarantee the win and would win in average $0.5$ dollar per bet.

Comment: Also risky is to continue with constant stakes until he is in plus because he can get arbitary far in the minus before this happens. But in practice, this would still have a good chance to win, if he does this only once.

Comment: The St.Petersburg situation would be extremely risky in practice. Only theoretical, the expected payout is unlimited. This is the reason why it is a paradox because despite of an infinite expectation, it would be not clever in practice to play the game with a fee of , lets say , $100$ dollars because almost all runs end in a loss.